# Weight exerted by two blocks of metal

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, weight, solid-mechanics

Can 2 blocks, composed of different metals, have the same masses but different volumes and still have the same weight if hung on a spring balance?

Comment: Is this a question about the equivalence of gravitational mass and inertial mass? There are many threads about that on this site.

Comment: @Pieter no it is not about that

Comment: is this about buoyancy?

Comment: Are the two blocks composed of the same metal?  Is each block "homogeneous" (e.g., no internal voids)?  Is each block weighed on the same planet, and in the same location?

Comment: @DavidWhite no they are composed of different metals

Comment: @DoniaElwardany, it would be helpful if you edited your question and added information to it.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you are asking. If the two blocks have the same mass, m, then why wouldn't they also have the same weight, mg?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Mass is a measure of the amount of material. Weight is amount of force from gravity pulling on the material.

$F = mg$, where g is a constant. So two blocks with the same m will have the same weight, F. Volume doesn't matter.